# Eclipse How to search and replace on the closing bracket of a method declaration

Tags: regex, eclipse, multiline

I think this is not supported in Eclipse, but I would like to find each closing bracket of each method I declare and replace it with one more code line before it closes.

I tried to find by regex "`public.*\}`" or "`public[.\s]*\}`" but it does not find a single method declaration.

Although some posts declare that Eclipse has multi-line search&replace capabilities, using regular expressions. I think it is not so.
The examples usually given just recognize a specific newline when the regex know where it is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible but not with regexp. Instead, write a small Java program and add `org.eclipse.jdt.core_3*.jar` to the classpath. You can find this JAR in the `plugins/` folder of your Eclipse installation.

The JAR contains the Eclipse compiler which has an API to convert Java source to the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Iterate over the AST, locale all methods and add the new code using AST nodes. There are methods to turn an AST into a string. Use that to generate the new source code.

If you have no idea how the new AST nodes should look like, add the code to a single method and print the result.

Another alternative would be to use [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) which allows you to wrap methods at runtime.

**[EDIT]** See the code in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.surround.SurroundWithTryCatchRefactoring`
for an example ([source on grepcode](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.7.0/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/surround/SurroundWithTryCatchRefactoring.java?av=f))

Comment: @AaronDigulla Thanks, I will look into it. Do you happen to know some working example, someone that has already used it to change the source code and has the code posted somewhere?

Comment: Yes. All the refactorings in Eclipse use this approach. See my edits.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible the way you try it because of nested `{}`. Regex cannot handle nesting.

Try inserting a new line *in front of* every `}\s*public` instead.

Comment: That's the challenge. Not all declarations are preceeded by declarations, so your suggestion would not work. :::: You know, if multiline was working as in perl, for example, we could search for `{.*?}` and be sure there are no nested  {}. :::: I grant that it would be a non-simple regex, but that's the question about.

Comment: @ilomambo No. If you search for `{.*?}` You get the first opening brace in the file and the first closing brace after that. Which would be the one after the first `if`. Regex cannot handle nesting. If a concept of nesting depth is required then the task, hoever simple it may seem, cannot be solved with regex.

Comment: You are Right, `{[^{]*?}` would find primitive non nested brackets. But you undestand I gave it as an example that with some ingenuity maybe a regex can be built. That would only be a small part of it, not the whole regex.

Comment: @ilomambo As I said. A regex that respects nested brackets (or nested *anythings*, for that matter) cannot be built. End of story.

Comment: Be open minded :-) [SEE THIS LINK](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-recursion) :::: One of many, even in this forum you can find more

Comment: @ilomambo The relevant portion of that article is *"Still, given that there is a known maximum amount of recursion that needs to be accounted for, it's quite possible"*. I take it that for arbitrary Java code there is a) no maximum bracket nesting depth and b) this does not even try to account for unbalanced brackets that are part of comments or strings. Just forget about it. This is not about being "closed-minded". It is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can match and replace nested brackets like this:

Search Pattern: ({(?:{?(?:\s|.)}?)*?)(})

Replace Pattern: $1\t// my code\n$2

However this isnt working in Eclipse, while it work with Java.

Comment: I tried it and it does not even compile in the find dialog "Illegal repetition near index 0" :::: Did it work for you? :::: Just saw your correction, I need it for Eclipse, to search/replace Java code I don't think I will write a program in Java to do it :::: If must, then I'll write it in perl.

Comment: I also found a mistake in my regexp search pattern. Its not possible to match with nested brackets as Tomalak already said. Since you do not know which ending bracket is the end of the function. Sorry.

Comment: Well you can match the right ending bracket when you make sure the indenting is correctly done. The trailing whitespace before the beginning bracket has to be the same as the trailing whitespace beofre the ending bracket. Like this: ((\s*)\{(?:\{?(?:\s|.)\}?)*?)\2(}). Replace pattern would be this: $1\n$2\t// my code\n$3. However that is still not working in Eclipse :(.

Comment: I'm pretty far making the patterns work in Eclipse. Give me some more time and I'll get back to you when I know more.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to plug all holes. Too much variables. I guess you should write a script for it instead, with possibly multiple regexp patterns.